# API for the browser AND react-native apps - how to handle auth?

Tags: react-native, authentication, flask, cookies, jwt

For the first time, we are developing a new project that needs to support the browser (a website) and a mobile app built on react-native.

We have plenty of experience developing for the web, but little to no experience in the mobile app world.

We are now defining our API and trying to make it work for both platforms - This will be a basic JSON API, running on Flask. The API will have some public endpoints, and some protected ones as well (that require auth). **We want a cross platform auth solution.**

Typically, for the web, we have always relied on cookie based sessions (encrypted) that frameworks like Flask provide. We have been successfully using these in various scenarios: loading HTML templates directly from the web framework, or even when the frontend application runs on React (same domain + `HttpOnly` + `secure` cookies).

The introduction of react-native could potentially bring some new challenges, and some of our developers worry about not being able to continue to use our typical session based cookies - They are advocating to using something like **JWT** for authorization, for both the browser and app (and yes, I know that we can't compare sessions to token based auth).

I'm not a big fan of token based authorization (for a number of reasons, could entertain that conversation if anyone wants to waste some time...), and I can't seem to understand why we shouldn't stick to our normal encrypted "Cookie" value.

Here is how I imagine this could work, based on using the Flask cookie session:

- A user hits `/api/login` with some credentials
- The endpoint will validate the user and return back whatever response + the `Set-Cookie` header with a value of `session=<encrypted string>`
- Any further requests from the browser/app would send back the cookie value again.

Essentially, nothing would change for typical browser implementations, this is how browsers work by default.

The react-native documentation mentions a few issues with cookie based authentication: https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#known-issues-with-fetch-and-cookie-based-authentication

From what I can gather (my knowledge is extremely limited on this subject), react-native might not always respect the `Set-Cookie` header. Which is OK - we would just have to make sure to send back the expected header with any further requests.

This, in theory, would fulfil our requirements.

**I'm looking for feedback on my "solution", am I missing anything? Did I get HTTP completely wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

React Native actually provides networking similar to that of websites developed with basic JavaScript, which also supports cookie based authentication, however there are some serious caveats as mentioned in [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network)

> The following options are currently not working with fetch
>
> - redirect:manual
> - credentials:omit
> - Having same name headers on Android will result in only the latest    one being present. A temporary solution can be found here:
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18837#issuecomment-398779994.
> - Cookie based authentication is currently unstable. You can view some    of the issues raised here:
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23185
> - As a minimum on iOS, when redirected through a 302, if a Set-Cookie    header is present, the cookie is not set properly. Since the redirect
>   cannot be handled manually this might cause a scenario where infinite
>   requests occur if the redirect is the result of an expired session.

Therefore, I would advise against using it as it is unstable and might give you a hard time dealing with it

I also suggest looking into frameworks that handle authentication for you, such as [auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native)

Hope you find this helpful :)